# Unix - link my internal server on port 9000 to the web

Tags: unix

I am on unix

I have an internal (on the machine) server running on port 9000

I want to access this server via my website, www.example.com

I would like to keep whatever i have already at www.example.com, but access my internal server via www.example.com/internal

What do I have to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reverse proxy in your web server.

For Apache HTTPD (and compatible), I recommend using [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with the proxy flag:

```
RewriteRule  ^/internal(/.*)?$  http://localhost:9000$1 [P]
```